# Conditional formatting in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to use conditional formatting to highlight consecutive cells in a column if they are populated. 
If there is only once cell that is populated followed by a blank row, I do not want to highlight that row.

Which formula should I use.

Answer (score 1):

Select entire column and apply conditional formatting with formula: `=COUNTBLANK(A1:A2)=0`:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]